Fetch Backend Server Without caching data
I'm using Next.js and I'm trying to fetch some data stored in my backend server. My back and my front are both deployed on Vercel. The problem is the data fetch doesn't change despite the number of requests.
Consequently, I use the cache no-store option in my fetch request to obtain a different response, this update works only for my local host and not for the frontend deployed.
This is the code which displays the frontend main page :
import styles from "../page.module.css";
import Card from "../components/card";
import { CardData } from "../lib/definitions";

export default async function Home() {
const getRandomCardFromDB = async () => {
const data = await fetch(
"https://example/randomcard",
{
cache: "no-store",
}
);
return (await data.json()) as CardData;
};

let card1: CardData = await getRandomCardFromDB();
let card2: CardData = await getRandomCardFromDB();

let i = 10;
while (i > 0) {
if (card1.name !== card2.name) break;
card2 = await getRandomCardFromDB();
i--;
}

return (






);
}


And this is the code of my backend :
router.get("/randomcard", async function (req, res, next) {
const client = await pool.connect();

let count = await client.query(`SELECT COUNT(Name) From Cards;`);
const randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (count.rows[0].count - 1));
  
let data = await client.query(
`SELECT * FROM Cards LIMIT 1 OFFSET ${randomIndex};`
);

console.log("Card selected from db : " + data.rows[0].name);
res.set("Cache-Control", "no-store");
res.json(data.rows[0]);
await client.release();
});

The data base used is the Postgresql db integrated with vercel deployment.
Moreover the localhost calls the backend API twice or more but the frontend deployment call it only once at each update.
I think I'm missing something with deployment option. But I don't figure it out.
Fetching data is working properly when my component is on 'use client'
